# Grafana: Panel [Time series transformation] merge many series into one

Tags: merge, prometheus, grafana, transformation, metrics

I'm building a Grafana panel to show when a circuit breaker (resilicence4j) changes its state. Metrics being sent to Prometheus looks like:

```
metric_name{instance=A, name=cb1, state=closed, value=1}
metric_name{instance=A, name=cb1, state=open, value=0}
metric_name{instance=A, name=cb1, state=half_open, value=0}
```

It's guaranteed when a circuit breaker enters in a particular state, its value will be 1 and all others will be 0. So using Grafana transformations (keeping only metrics which value = 1) I reached the following table result:

| Time | instance | name | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:00 | A | cb1 | closed |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:15 | A | cb1 | open |
| 2022-06-25 17:00:30 | A | cb1 | half_open |
| 2022-06-26 17:00:45 | A | cb1 | closed |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:00 | A | cb2 | closed |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:15 | A | cb2 | closed |
| 2022-06-25 17:00:30 | A | cb2 | open |
| 2022-06-26 17:00:45 | A | cb2 | half_open |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:00 | B | cb | open |
| 2022-06-24 17:00:15 | B | cb | half_open |
| 2022-06-25 17:00:30 | B | cb | closed |
| 2022-06-26 17:00:45 | B | cb | closed |

I want to build a time series panel that my axis X would be the time value, my axis Y would be state (name, not value) and each group of instance and name would be a series. I've tried many combinations of transformations to do something like this, but I've never got the expected result. Any clues how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the Time Series panel, you need numeric values in your query result for visualization. Also, the y-axis is always numeric. So your initial query result should contain the *state* as a numeric value. Also each column is treated as a series, so your columns should be for example *A_cb1*, *A_cb2*, *B_cb* and contain the respective numeric state values.

You can then use [`Value mappings`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/format-data/about-value-mapping/) to map the *state* to words. Those words will then be displayed in the tooltip when you hover over the series, however, the y-axis will always stay numeric.

I recommend you have a look at the [State Timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/state-timeline/) panel for your visualization. You could use the same query result and value mappings, but have the words displayed and no y-axis at all.